# How to retrieve missed calls on Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any possibility of retrieving missed phone call numbers from WP7? As far as I know, third party apps will be tombstonded on incoming calls. So there is no way of implementing a caller id request to a web service based phone book provider... Question is: will I manage to look up the number, when I missed the call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to access information about missed or dialled calls in Windows Phone 7. For security reasons, any applicaiton you write is essentially sandboxed from user data such as phone numbers unless the user specifically provides it directly or via the `PhoneNumberChooserTask` (or similar).

This was a deliberate design consideration for the first version of the SDK/API. This may or may not change in the future, no-one is saying or can say for sure. But, for now you can't.